# jqgrid not executing when bound to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jquery-events

I'm not sure why this isn't working but probably because I'm not very familiar with jJavascript.

The following is initialised

```
$('#categoryList').find('.sideboxEntry').live("click", function() {
    productBindToGrid();
});
productBindToGrid();

function productBindToGrid(filterBy) {
    $("#productGridView").jqGrid();
}
```

`productBindToGrid()` is entered and `.jqGrid()` fires on initialization but when `.sideboxEntry` is clicked it is entered too but `.jqGrid()` doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read the documentation. Once initialised, you should trigger a reload using

```
$("#productGridView").trigger("reloadGrid");
```